# Audio .mp3 file can not play for sometimes for website background

Tags: javascript, php

mp3 file for giving  background music to website but it will play for sometimes only. It will occur error:

> 206 partial content

Please give some solution to the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// PLAYER VARIABLES

var mp3snd = "5.mp3";

document.write('<audio autoplay="autoplay">');
document.write('<source src="'+mp3snd+'" type="audio/mpeg">');
document.write('</audio>');

</script>
```

Comment: Use document.appendChild, not write, you may use .write to write a text, not a html tag.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark said, avoid to use `document.write`. Also it's better to avoid using autoplay, since browsers block it nowadays.
All sounds should start with the user agreement, or on click.

I also suggest to use preload for performance.

```
let mp3snd = new Audio("sounds/youur.mp3");
mp3snd.preload = 'auto';
mp3snd.load();

const playMp3snd = volumeValue => {
    var backgroundMusic = mp3snd.cloneNode();
    backgroundMusic .volume = volumeValue;
    backgroundMusic .play();
}
playMp3snd(1);
```

Comment: I am using php When i give as path  localhost:81/foldername it not work but when i click on index.php it will work plz need solution